# Variable Declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
         `DECLARE @MYACCOUNT CHAR(2),
         @REPORTTYPE CHAR(1),
         @BRANCHCODE CHAR(3)


         SELECT @MYACCOUNT='SV',
         @REPORTTYPE='D',
         @BRANCHCODE='001'

         IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TBL_Category WHERE CategoryType=@MYACCOUNT)
         SELECT 'INVALID ACCOUNT NAME IS : '+@MYACCOUNT

         ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TBL_Category WHERE CatGroup=@REPORTTYPE)
         SELECT 'INVALID REPORT NAME IS : '+@REPORTTYPE

         ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM BranchMaster WHERE MBranchCode=@BRANCHCODE)
         SELECT 'INVALID BRANCH CODE IS : '+@BRANCHCODE

         ELSE
           SELECT M.MBranchCode, SUM(M.MMiscBaln) FROM MasterTable M, TBL_Category T
           WHERE T.CategoryCode=M.MAcType
           AND T.CategoryType=@MYACCOUNT
           AND T.CatGroup=@REPORTTYPE
           AND M.MBranchCode=@BRANCHCODE
           GROUP BY M.MBranchCode`
```

I want a solution that when I enter the wrong data in variables then it should throw error message. There may be more than one error but should display error of those variables.
For example:

If I entered value:

```
                `@BRANCHCODE='002'
               @REPORTTYPE='A'
               @MYACCOUNT='SQ'`
```

@BRANCHCODE is correct. Then it should throw message that @REPORTTYPE and @MYACCOUNT is error.

Comment: Turn off your caps lock, that is incredibly hard to read.

Comment: thanks. now will u answer my question?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Don't use `ELSE`. Keep track of whether _any_ error has been printed, and if so skip the main body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect your error messages, if you get none return the result of your query, else return or raise the collected errormessages.

```
Declare @a Table (a int,b int,c int)

insert into @a Values(1,2,3),(4,4,4)

Declare @va int=2
Declare @vb int=2
Declare @vc int=2

Declare @error Varchar(100)=''
if not exists(select * from @a where a=@va)
   Select @Error=@Error + 'Invalid va ' + Cast(@va as Varchar(10)) + Char(13)+Char(10)
if not exists(select * from @a where b=@vb)
   Select @Error=@Error + 'Invalid vb ' + Cast(@vb as Varchar(10)) + Char(13)+Char(10)
if not exists(select * from @a where c=@vc)
   Select @Error=@Error + 'Invalid vc ' + Cast(@vc as Varchar(10)) + Char(13)+Char(10)
if len(@Error)>0 select @Error
else
  Select * from @a where a=@va and b=@vb and c=@vc
```